# Rendering images in a content query webpart

Tags: content-query-web-part, picture

I have a bunch of images in a picture library that I want to expose on my Sharepoint homepage. I've added a Content Query webpart and configured it to display the items in the picture library list which is fine. However the images are displayed one on top of the other which isn't very aesthetic.

I would like to display the images side by side. Presumably I have to edit the ItemStyle.xsl file. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this please as I'm struggling a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

Check following link to do multi column layout using CQWP

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/displaying-results-in-multiple-columns-using-the-content-query-web-part/

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/displaying-results-in-multiple-columns-using-the-content-query-web-part-the-other-direction/

Answer (score 1):

Just add a css style into your page will solve this:

```
<style>
    .dfwp-item {
      float:left;
    }
</style>
```

You can add the css statement into your page directly (by SharePoint Designer) or put a Content Editor Web Part into your page and set its Html Source with the css statement.