# Gridview for picture library with link

Tags: hyperlink, picture-library, gridview

Is there a out of box way to use the picture library on a page that will have grid view with link on the picture?
[image]

Comment: I would like to thank Jony for his effort on this post.
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34052/getting-last-three-images-with-xsllistviewwebpart/34072#34072 Basically this solved my issue. Thanks Jony

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting last three images with XSLListViewWebPart](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34052/getting-last-three-images-with-xsllistviewwebpart)